# What is that beeping noise?

Tags: electrical, circuit

When my GF & I lay in bed late at night, we can hear continuous beeping somewhere nearby. The tone & rhythm of the beeping is exactly like an alarm clock, but we don't own one, nor do the neighbors. Is there anything in electrical wiring or plumbing that could possibly make this noise? Has anyone else had this happen? It's driving us insane.

Comment: Search using the word “beeping” to find numerous similar. Questions

Comment: I've looked at some but none have anything that only happens at night

Comment: crickets or frogs outside?  smoke detector? somebody's prank? electrical appliance running on battery back up (like a UPS) and the outlet it was plugged into is switched off?

Comment: How many guesses do i get and how will you know if i guess correctly?

Comment: Something plugged into a receptacle that is controlled by the light switch. Like Mark f suggested. Lots of houses had receptacles that control a plug in lamp by the bed for example

Comment: You'll have to get out of bed and walk around the house/appt/flat until you zero in on where it's coming from.

Comment: an audio clip is worth 1000 words in this case.

Comment: I hear it too. Weird.

Comment: Wait you're messing with me right?

Comment: What smoke or CO detectors or similar do you have?  Sometimes as the batteries get low, they chirp or bleep.  At night when the air gets cooler, can push a marginal battery over the edge but its okay again when things warm up.

Comment: Or have you upset someone enough to covertly install a thinkgek annoyatron ? 
  https://www.thegreenhead.com/2008/12/annoy-a-tron-2.php

Comment: For 8 years I had this "beep" sound going off once a minute at the lodge kitchen.  I turned the place inside and out many times looking for it.  Then I realized, they put up some foam insulation sheets across the rafters around 2001, and the only possibility is they had buried a smoke detector up there.  So I got a ladder and took off dozens of screws to get the sheet panel partly down, listened up in there, and the sound came from below me!  *It was sitting on a shelf in plain view, the whole time*.

Comment: That's interesting. You aren't claiming this story as anything paranormal or supernatural though, right?

Answer (score 1):

I’d turn off all the electricity by turning off all the circuit breakers, including refrigerator, oven, etc. This will determine if it’s electrically powered or battery powered.

If that works, you can slowly restarting each circuit. If not, start checking battery powered items...room by room.

Comment: Thank you, will do tonight. I just don't understand why it only happens at night time though. Any possible explanations?

Comment: Is it at the same exact time each night?

Comment: Yes it starts at about 11 and ends whenever, usually when we wake up its off

Comment: I’d make sure all the circuit breakers are off well before 11 then.

Comment: I will do for sure, I still don't get WHY IT only happens then, I've never heard of this before

Answer (score 0):

A little late but had this happening just now and found out it was literally a charger... I could hear it even while in another room. I have no idea the issue on why it's doing it though.